# How to make a part of an image Black?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I would to make a part of an image black before applying the distance transform algorithm

I have tried to create a black image and use the Logic Gate functions in opencv but to no avail.

I would like to change the white region(marked with arrow) to black and then apply the distance transform algorithm :

[image: Code and Image]

is it possible to pass a kernel of a particular size but only with zeros? And wherever the kernel matches, replace it with a mask of a particular size but only with ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im' not entirely sure by what criterion you define which part is to be made black.

If the black area is known in advance you can just use use an image of the black mask and combine them using `cv::Multiply(mask, image)`

If you want to automatically black out a connected white area starting from a given point you can use `cv::floodFill`. Details can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill)